# Get change date of a folder in Go

Tags: go

I want to get the date when a folder was renamed, from terminal it can be done using the `stat` command, e.g.:

```
> stat -x folders/folder1
File: "folders/folder1"
Size: 64           FileType: Directory
Mode: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)         Uid: (2006390509/username)  Gid: 
(296108113/EMEA\Domain Users)
Device: 1,4   Inode: 2599274    Links: 2
Access: Mon Nov 12 17:59:57 2018
Modify: Mon Nov 12 14:12:20 2018
Change: Mon Nov 12 17:28:01 2018
```

The change date is the last date the folder's metadata was changed, which includes renaming.

Is there any way to get it with Go without using `os.exec` and parsing the output? `os.Stat` seems to provide only the last modification date which doesn't change when the folder is renamed.

Comment: "Is there any way to get it with Go without using os.exec and parsing the output?" I don't see any reason why not; you know the command to get the output and you know what format it's in. Are you having some trouble doing that? Can you show the code you're having trouble with?

Comment: @Adrian it works, but I wonder if there is a better and cleaner way to get this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change time is not accessible in `os.FileInfo` but can be get via `os.FileInfo.Sys()` which stores that data.

You can get it by

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Stat("your/dir")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("err reading: %v", err)
    }

    //access change time saved in os.FileInfo.Sys()
    changeTime := f.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t).Ctim

    fmt.Print(time.Unix(changeTime.Unix()).String())
}
```

Ofcourse you need to check if `f.Sys()` it's proper type, but yeah `syscall.Stat_t.Ctim` is probably what you wanted.

Comment: I think, in macOS one has to replace `Ctim` with `Ctimespec`

Comment: If that's true then in `f.Sys()` it need to be other typ because `syscall.Stat_t` don't have `Ctimspec`. If Ctim is not accessible you need to call reflection on `f.Sys()` to get it type.

Comment: In mac `syscall.Stat_t` doesn't have `Ctim`, but has `Ctimspec`, it seems to be the same.

Comment: Indeed https://golang.org/src/syscall/ztypes_darwin_amd64.go line `76` `syscall.Stat_t` for `darwin` os have `Ctimespec`. It's wired why they do that beetwen os'es

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with calling os.Exec maybe you don't mind cross-platform issues. There was some discussion about this on a [github issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3952) a while back.

This code works for me to get the changed time anyway. Not sure how/if it'll work on Windows:

```
file, err := os.Open("test")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

stat, err := file.Stat()
sys := stat.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t)
changedTime := time.Unix(sys.Ctim.Unix())

fmt.Println(stat.ModTime())
fmt.Println(changedTime)
```

When I run

```
mv test test1 && mv test1 test && go run main.go
```

It gives me:

```
2018-11-12 17:31:38.659095951 +0000 GMT
2018-11-12 17:57:43.042208583 +0000 GMT
```

Which seems to correctly reflect the time I changed the dirname, and not the creation time (as in the first date)